# Alamofire .POST encoding (.URL)

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire, postman

So, I'm trying to do a `.POST` request with Alamofire with the default option:

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON
```

This one works just fine. As the documentation says, the default encoding for parameters is `.URL`.

Now I'm trying to improve my code creating routers following this guide:
https://grokswift.com/router/

In the end of the implementation is needed to encode the parameters manually. So, if the default was working, I'm using the `.URL` encoding here now, like so:

```
    let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL
    let (encodedRequest, _) = encoding.encode(urlRequest, parameters: parameters)
```

Now the request won't work, as the parameters are apparently are being sent in the wrong format.

I'm pretty sure the API is functional, I'm testing it in Postman and the parameters are being sent with the `form-data` option.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me!

Comment: maybe you can try using alamofire's `multipartFormData`

Comment: @Tj3n I thought of this. But how can it work without `multipartFormData` in the default request, but not in the router, if the encoding method is the same?

Comment: im not so sure about this :D maybe you can try print out the request's HTTPBody and decode it back to see the value?

Comment: There's probably some HTTP header difference between the two requests. Maybe you're not setting the `Content-Type` header in the latter approach?

Comment: That can be it! @AaronBrager I'm not checking this, going to try in a few moments!

Comment: @AaronBrager just tried it out, the headers are now the same, but with the debugPrint I can see that the `curl` out put is missing the `-d` statement. Any ideas?

Comment: @Victor I don't think the `-d` should be there based on the info you provided - you are not providing an HTTP body, only a URL and headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was working before, double-check that it was using URL encoding:

```
let postRequest = Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters)
  .validate()
  .responseJSON { ... }
debugPrint(postRequest)
```

That should show you the equivalent cURL statement for your request.

Then change the router to use `.URL` encoding and see if `debugPrint` output changes.

Comment: Hey! I just tried this out, and it is in fact .URL encoding by default. When I use `Alamofire.request default implementation`, like so: `Alamofire.request(.POST, baseApiAddress, parameters: parameters, encoding: .URL).validate().responseJSON` or `Alamofire.request(.POST, baseApiAddress+"/users", parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON`, the request works the same, so it is in fact .URL encoding. But when I try to do the router just like I said, the .URL encoding does not work.

Comment: Oh, and the debug print is the same!

Comment: done some digging, and with `debugPrint` I can see that the headers are the same between the default `Alamofire.request` and when using the routers described in the question, the `cURL` in the router is missing the `-d` statement and the parameters are into the `URL` itself. When using the default implementation, the parameters are into the `-d` statement and not in the `URL`. Both are using `.URL` encoding option. Any ideas of what can be happening?

Comment: Check if you're setting the HTTP method (.POST) before `let (encodedRequest, _) = encoding.encode(urlRequest, parameters: parameters)`

Comment: That was it! I needed to set the method before encoding the parameters... Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience in Swift and Objective-C, while we are making request with POST then there should not be require to pass URL with encoding unless until there is any special characters or space is there.

If you are making GET request then you should always pass URL with encoding. In POST, what ever your parameters are, passed as form-data in body it self. Not any code require their.

So, in your code, just remove URL Encode part from POST method.

Answer (score -1):

you can set parameter encoding as JSON  as well.

```
let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON
```